# CakePHP: How to ensure there's always at least one item in a belongsTo relationship?

Tags: cakephp

Let's say, I have business rules that an article has many comments and a comment can only be deleted as long as it's not the last one, except for when I delete the article, then all comments should be deleted as well.

Currently I have in the CommentsTable class this code in buildRules:

```
$rules->addDelete(fn($entity, $options) => $this->findByArticleId($entity->article_id)->count() > 1);
```

When I try to delete an article, I however get a `NestedTransactionRollbackException` in CORE/src/Database/Connection.php:562.

How can I detect in the rules that the article is about to be deleted and thus the deletion of all comments, even the last one, is okay?

I use CakePHP 4.1 with [a soft delete behavior](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Trash), which requires me to use `'cascadeCallbacks' => true` in the association, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting `hasMany` associations works by deleting the children before the parent, and the business rules process doesn't really know much about the outside world, it can't really tell in what context something is being deleted.

At most it can check whether or not the operation is part of a cascading association operation. The `_primary` option, which if `true`, indicates an explicit operation on the model that the rule belongs to, so say `$commentsTable->delete($entity)` instead of a cascading `$articlesTable->delete($entity)`, in which case the `_primary` option would be `false`.

If that information is good enough for you, go for it.

```php
$rules->addDelete(
    function ($entity, $options)  {
        if ($options['_primary'] === false) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($this->findByArticleId($entity->article_id)->count() > 1) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
);
```

If you need more information about the initiator of the operation, then there's not really much you can do besides passing in custom options that you can evaluate in your rules, for example like this:

```php
$articlesTable->delete($entity, ['_source' => $articlesTable])
```

You could of course implement that in the table itself, for example by overriding `delete()`.